# Patrick Jane and his teas

Tags: product-placement, the-mentalist

I can recall Patrick Jane having a tea-break in many (most?) of the episodes that I've watched.
I suspect that in many (most?) cases it's a tactical move, nevertheless I think that he really enjoyed his cup.

1. Did Mr. Jane ever discuss the particular brand(s) he most enjoys?
2. I don't recall a tea bag shown in sufficient detail to think "product-placement", but I may be wrong…

On another note, not related to product placement: had Jane tea bags in his pockets as a matter of abitude?

Comment: It could just be an homage to Hercules Poirot, the Agatha Christie character who loved to drink herbal tea.

Comment: 1. No  2. No

He just likes to have his cuppa. that's all. did you notice the lack of starbucks references? that's because Jane liked having Tea.

also, see this quote : https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-8d34660abab7585daa4421f48dde298b-lq